# Retomar valor de URL php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo la siguiente URL

https://midominio.com/carpeta/0

cuando creao el archivo json y lo coloco en la carpeta le coloco el nombre así y me lo lee. Ahora bien, quisiera hacer algo dinamico, de tal manera que pueda tomar el valor "0" y con el hacer una consulta a una base de datos.

Como puedo obtener el valor "0" con php? y como crear el archivo para que al hacer la consulta me muestre el json correspondiente?

Comment: Puedes utilizar [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) que es una función de PHP. En cuanto a la consulta no se si lo que quieres es que genere un json o transformar un string(con formato json) en un objeto json. Si es la 1º puedes utilizar [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php). Y si es la 2º puedes utilizar [`json_decode($string, true)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Lo que deseo es saber como puedo llamar a la consulta y si es posible hacerlo. Actualmente tengo 10 archivos listados así: 0-10 cuando entras a la url no te genera error alguno por que encuentra el archivo. Sin embargo cuando coloco un archivo index.php y la persona entra a www.midominuo.com/micarpeta/0 sale un error de archivo no encontrado. Quiero conocer si hay manera de encontrar el archivo. Las salidas en json se como configurarlas, pero ni idea de como encontrar el parametro y que no me genere el error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer puede resolverse en varios puntos, los cuales trataré de explicar de forma resumida. El procedimiento a continuación vale si queremos crear por ejemplo una API, con sus puntos de entrada, de forma que podamos usar URLs amigables.

### 1. Redirecciones en el `.htaccess`

Si ya no lo tienes, tienes que redirigir todas las peticiones que lleguen al punto de entrada `carpeta` a un archivo `index.php` que tendrás en ese directorio. Para ello, pones esto en el `.htaccess` de `carpeta`:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off   #BORRA ESTA LÍNEA SI TU DOMINIO NO ES HTTPS
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]  #BORRA ESTA LÍNEA SI TU DOMINIO NO ES HTTPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

No tiene que haber nada más en carpeta. Debería quedar así:

```
+-- public_html
    +-- carpeta
    |   +-- .htaccess
    |   +-- index.php
```

### 2. Controlar peticiones en `index.php`

En `index.php` puedes conocer el contenido de la URL y sus partes mediante el uso de `$_GET['PATH_INFO']` o  de otro modo.

El código establece un control para no dejar pasar peticiones que no estén autorizadas. Digamos, que si la petición no es un valor entre `0` y `10`, no pasará. Esto es particularmente útil en el contexto de una API expuesta de manera pública, evitando solicitudes sin control que pueden ser enviadas incluso por bots o por hackers.

Vamos a ello:

```
#Buscamos lo que se escribió en la URL
if (isset($_GET['PATH_INFO'])){
    $req = explode('/', $_GET['PATH_INFO']);
    #Obtenemos cómo termina la URL
    $endPoint = array_shift($req);
    #Array con los puntos de entrada permitidos, todo lo que no sea esto será rechazado
    $allowed = array(
                      '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'
                     );
} else {
    $output=array ("error"=>"No se reconoce la petición");
}

#Se verifica si la última parte de la URL está en el array de recursos permitidos
if (!in_array($endPoint, $allowed)) {
        $output=array ("error"=>"No se reconoce el recurso $endPoint al que intentas acceder");
}else{
    /* 
       Se establece un control de métodos
       Es opcional, pero aumenta la seguridad
       si por ejemplo sólo quieres admitir métodos GET y/o POST, etc
    */
    $metodo = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    switch ($metodo) {
    case 'get':
            #Trabajar con $endPoint y meter la respuesta en un array $output
            break;

    case 'post':
            #Trabajar con $endPoint y meter la respuesta en un array $output
            break;

    default:
        $output=array ("error"=>"Método no permitido");
        break;
    }
}
/* 
    Pensando en una API, he puesto todas las salidas en un array, 
    para luego responder con un JSON, que es el medio de transporte habitual para estos casos
    Cuando se consuma la petición se podría buscar si el JSON tiene una propiedad error o no
    para saber cómo manejar la respuesta
    Se podría usar también una vista para emitir 
    distintos tipos de salida según la necesidad (json, html, text, xml, etc)
*/
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($output);
```

Eso es todo. Con este código, podrás trabajar con `$endPoint` dentro de la parte del `switch` para hacer lo que tengas que hacer. Aquí `index.php` sería una especie de controlador, si pensamos en un modelo `MVC` y podrías desde el `get` o los otros case, pasar la información al modelo  y sacar los datos usando la vista.

## Ejemplo

Haciendo eso, las URL serían escritas así:

```
http://www.tudominio.com/carpeta/0
http://www.tudominio.com/carpeta/3
http://www.tudominio.com/carpeta/7
```

... Etc

Eso no termina ahí, basándote en eso puedes montar una API mucho más compleja con diversos puntos de entrada. Siempre trabajando la información que recuperes en `$_GET['PATH_INFO']` crearás una lógica en `index.php` para dirigir cada petición a donde tenga que ir.

Algunos ejemplos:

Buscar el usuario cuyo `id` es `10`:

```
http://www.tudominio.com/usuario/id/10
```

Buscar una lista de productos vendidos del agente (vendedor) `007`  :)

```
http://www.tudominio.com/list/products/vendor/007
```

Etc, etc, etc.

OJO, todo esto se determinaría en el archivo `index.php` que haría de controlador. Como consejo, cuando implementes algo así usa un modelo tipo `MVC` u otro, de modo que uses el modelo para obtener/organizar los datos y la vista para mostrarlos, así no metes toda la lógica en un interminable archivo `index.php`, sobre todo en proyectos más o menos grandes.

Si hay alguna duda, puedes preguntar en comentarios. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Como puedo incluir una consulta Mysql en el bucle o el array allowed?

Comment: @JesusMoran el array `$allowed` representa los puntos de entrada permitidos, si quieres agregar otro punto de entrada sólo lo agregas al array, por ejemplo: `'10', '11', 'usuario'` ahí, aparte de `10`, que ya estaba, hemos permitido peticiones al punto de entrada `11` y también `usuario`, ahora se aceptarán URLs con esos dos valores.

Comment: o sea que si hago una consulta php+mysql yo puedo establecer que el array de la consulta cuyo valor id (autoincrement, int, 11, primary key) sea el valor o los valores permitidos?

Comment: Si así lo necesitas claro que se puede. Lo que hace aquí `$allowed` es establecer qué puntos de entrada pueden ser consultados y si en la URL hay algo que no este en `$alllowed` no se realizará la consulta.

Comment: Hola, tu respuesta me ha servido de mucho, ahora necesito saber si es posible pasar esa variable que tomo en php a java, estoy tratando de comunicarme con un contrato inteligente y eso lo hago desde java, no se como pasar esa variable que estoy tomando

Comment: @JesusMoran generalmente en estos casos se programa una API o un Servicio Web, que recibe desde Java la petición y responde con un JSON (puede ser también un XML u otro, pero JSON es lo más usado). Luego en Java consumes los datos. En contextos más complejos te puedes valer de librerías como GSon para mapear tu respuesta a las clases de tu modelo. De todos modos este es un tema totalmente aparte que deberías plantear en otra pregunta, para que sea más visible a otros usuarios y obtengas una ayuda más precisa. Con lo comentado ya tienes alguna pista a explorar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomar tu tiempo y responder, tengo una pregunta, como puedo hacer este mismo sistema pero en java? es posible? algun link que me pueda referenciar o un codigo que pueda usar? de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: @JesusMoran ¿cuando dices "en Java" te refieres a Java como lenguaje en el servidor o en el cliente?

Comment: imagino que en el cliente, es para insertarlo en un html

Comment: Tienes que explicarlo y tenerlo claro. O sea, si los datos están en el servidor (base de datos, PHP, etc) y los vas a pedir desde un cliente cualquiera (digamos una aplicación escrita en Java) en el servidor nada cambia, desde Java enviarías una petición al servidor mediante una URL, el servidor te respondería con un JSON que consumirlas en Java para mostrarlo en un html o donde sea. Esa es la idea. De cualquier modo lo que preguntas sería tema para una nueva pregunta dónde expongas las dudas que tienes y lo que has intentado hasta el momento.