# Problema con llamado GET en PHP

Tags: php

Les comento que tengo un script en donde llama a las paginas sin que se vea la extencion `.php`

Algo asi:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']){
    include 'phpfiles/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
} else {
    include 'phpfiles/deff.php';
}
?>
```

Dentro del directorio `phpfiles` se encuentran el archivo `shop.php` que lista productos y `product.php` que segun su codigo me da el detalle del producto seleccionado.

Dentro de `shop.php`

```
<a href="./?page=product?code=<?=$fila['codigo'];?>"> // codigo de producto
  <img src="<?=$fila['imagen'];?>" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><?=$fila['titulo'];?></h5>
    <h4 class="card-text"><?=$fila['valor'];?></h4>
</a>
```

Y dentro de `product.php` quiero obtener el codigo del producto.

```
<?php

$codigo = $_GET['code'];
echo $codigo;

?>
```

Al tratar de hacer esto, el error que me da es:

> Warning: include(phpfiles/product?@=d5e4hdhai.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Lo que veo que hace es que al codigo le agrega la extension `.php`: `d5e4hdhai.php` y es por eso que no me deje ver el codigo del producto dentro de `product.php`. Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Usa `sprintf` para concatenar el código php con .php y avísame si te sigue dando el mismo problema, el código quedaría como `$file = sprintf("%s.php", $_GET["page"]); include __DIR__ . "/" . $file;`

Comment: Gracias Fernando, pero tambien me da error, y hasta me cambia la barra, lo cual no encuentra el directorio

Comment: Deberías revisar lo que estás enviando en `page`, puedes poner un `var_dump($_GET['page']);` para depurar, al parecer lo que estás pasando es esto: `product?@=d5e4hdhai.php` lo cual no es correcto. Dinos qué se debería pasar a través de `page`. ¿? Te sugeríría en cualquier caso que uses URL amigagles, así te evitas el royo de la extensión PHP y podrías pasar valores así por ejemplo: `http://www.tudominio/ruta/product/d5e4` etc. [Aquí hay más detalles sobre eso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967), si te interesa explorar esa posibilidad.

Comment: `page` toma el nombre del directorio y le asigna la extension `.php`. Lo que pasa en `product?@=d5e4hdhai.php` es que toma el codigo del producto y le asigna la extension. Con las url amigables, no fueron muy amigables conmigo o algo hice mal que no pude resolver y opte por hacer esto.

Comment: Leyendo el `Warning: include(phpfiles/product?@=d5e4hdhai.php): failed to open stream` se ve claramente que en `$_GET["page"]` está llegando algo como esto: **`product?@=d5e4hdhai`** ¿Pusiste el `var_dump` para confirmar eso? Por otra parte, aunque las URL amigables no te funcionaron no lo descartes, te animo a volver sobre ello, cuando organizas el código así luego trabajas cómodamente y tu código funciona con más seguridad, más flexibilidad y tiene el aspecto de una verdadera API.

Comment: El `var_dump` de arroja esto: `string(20) "product/?@=d5e4hdhai"`

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que el error que tuve fue con `.htaccess`, no lo recuerdo, pero me dio un dolor de cabeza que me habia frustrado. Voy a volver a retomarlo despues de leer [tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305983/retomar-valor-de-url-php/306018#306018), asi lo hago tranquilo.

Comment: Para lo que expones en esta pregunta revisa lo que te dice @RobertNiño en su respuesta, debes mandar bien la URL. De todos modos es muy raro lo que quieres hacer, realmente no estás evitando la extensión `.php`, no al menos de este modo, porque el GET tiene que ser mandado a un archivo `.php` que lo procese y la extensión tiene que estar. La otra solución es usar URL amigables. Es cuestión de poner el `.htaccess` en la carpeta a donde irían dirigidas las peticiones, poner en esa carpeta un archivo `index.php` que serviría de controlador para redirigir cada petición a donde tenga que ir y ya.

Comment: Si si... lo vi estaba probando. Gracias por la info y la ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

por lo que veo el problema esta en la ruta

```
<a href="./?page=product?code=<?=$fila['codigo'];?>"> // codigo de producto
```

cuando el php procesa la ruta de a href genera lo siguiente a partir de tu código

"?page=product?code=26"

en las rutas cuando vas a pasar por get múltiples datos primero se inicia el metodo con 
"?" y despues el resto de variables que pases tienes que concatenarla con "&"

tiene que generalo asi `"?page=product&code=26"`

por lo cual el cambio que tienes que hacer es

```
 <a href="./?page=product&code=<?=$fila['codigo'];?>"> // codigo de producto
```

también tienes que tener cuidado cuando utilizas `="./?page= // el punto de concatenación`

ya que estas trabajando con un código para no llamar la extencion .php pues ese punto esta de mas por que todas las rutas trabajan directo con el controlador que hiciste para evitar las rutas no es necesario y es redundante, por que el punto va a retroceder solo con colocar el "/?page=" es suficiente el navegador va a enterder por defecto que va a utilizar la ruta a partir del url base

```
    <a href="/?page=product&code=<?=$fila['codigo'];?>"> // codigo final
```

Comment: Ahi hice la prueba y funciona bien. MI idea era hacer url amigables y como dije antes, tuve problemas al implementarlas e hice este script asi ya no tenia que estar lidieando con algo que no logre entender. @a-cesano dejo un ejemplo de como trabajar con urls y bueno, a tratar de darle solucion a mi problema. Por el momento trabaje asi. Gracias por la info Robert.

Comment: Pues de nada amigo. Yo pues también hace mucho tiempo que trabaja así como tu lo estas haciendo entonces tengo algo de conocimiento, Pues yo ahora trabajo es con Laravel y te lo recomiendo muchísimo ó trabaja con cualquier framework que te llame la atención, pues no son malas y te ahorras muchas cosas

Comment: Me han recomendado Laravel varias veces, creo que debo hacer caso a esa recomendacion. Muchas gracias!