# URLs amigables en .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reescritura-url

Digamos que yo tenía la siguiente URL:

> http://localhost/index.php?lang=es&seccion=inicio

y con la siguiente regla en .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

logré que quedara así:

> http://localhost/?lang=es&seccion=inicio

Mi duda es, ¿qué más debo añadir para dejarlo de la siguiente forma?

> http://localhost/es/inicio

Mil gracias por adelantado

Comment: En el asunto de las url amigables, no se trata solamente de que sean bonitas, debe haber también un control, para que no se admitan peticiones cualesquiera sino sólo aquellas que estén permitidas. Hoy día hay bots que mandan peticiones a mansalva en los sitios webs, por lo tanto debes controlar eso si piensas publicar tu contenido. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967) he tratado de explicar la forma de hacerlo, te dejo el enlace porque creo que podría serte de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes de establecer reglas con la [directiva](http://es.voidcc.com/question/p-bgqvyocu-ba.html) `^` (circunflejo), además de ayudarte con una expresión regular simple.

El ejemplo que te propongo (y que lo tomo de tu código proporcionado previamente) es el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?lang=$1&seccion=$2
```

De esta manera, en tu archivo `index.php` ya podrías recibir tus variables por [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) como lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$lang = $_GET["lang"];
$seccion= $_GET["seccion"];
?>
```

En el mismo artículo donde te cité el símbolo de circunflejo, encontrarás una mejor explicación sobre la expresión regular utilizada.

Además, al final de esta respuesta, podrás encontrar un artículo interesante donde habla acerca de las urls amigables y así puedas ampliar mucho más tus conocimientos acerca de este tema.

Te mando saludos, espero que lo anterior explicado te haya sido de ayuda. Permíteme saber si tienes alguna duda o inconveniente al respecto.

**EDIT**

En orden de forzar el `.htaccess` de reconocer que está en el `index.php` y que se le mandan parámetros, ocupa el siguiente `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*?)$ index.php?lang=$1&seccion=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Ahora solo te falta visita tu url:

> http://localhost/es/inicio

---

William Wong Garay. (2006). Optimizando una web con urls amigables con Apache y PHP. 2020, de maestrosdelweb Sitio web: http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/urlamigable/

Comment: Hola Fernando, tu respuesta contiene información útil. Sin embargo, puedes mejorarla corrigiendo algunos errores tipográficos. También me reservo un voto `+1` a la espera de que la edición se concrete.

Comment: Gracias, @DavidE.LunaM. He editado la respuesta en orden que quede lo más clara posible, espero haberlo hecho mejor y que mi respuesta sea de ayuda hacia la comunidad.

Comment: Listo, pude observar la edición, aunque solo falta reemplazar **Desbes** por **Debes**.Lo demás quedó bien, por lo que ambos quedaron marcadas como pregunta y respuesta útil.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, @DavidE.LunaM. Ha quedado editada.

Comment: Excelente Fernando

Comment: Hola Fernando. Gracias por la respuesta, pero no surte efecto. El enlace se queda tal y como estaba.

Comment: Trata de ver si no es caché, visita tu navegador en modo incógnito

Comment: Si, ya lo había hecho pero nada. Lo que hice fue añadirle esa regla a lo que ya había entonces, y también probé a añadirlo eliminando todo lo anterior. Todo en modo incógnito y nada.

Comment: Por favor ve mi actualización

Comment: Perfecto, funciona, pero me surge el inconveniente de que no cargan los estilos de la página.

Comment: Hola, eso ya tiene que ver con otro problema, y se debe a que dentro de tu index o de tus páginas donde usas urls amigables tienes que poner las rutas absolutas, no las rutas relativas, es decir, en lugar de usar `../../css/estilos.css` usa `http://www.tupagina.com/css/estilos.css`, por poner un ejemplo. Si te sirvió esta respuesta, márcala como una respuesta aceptada para que otros que tengan el mismo problema conozcan la solución, saludos.

Comment: Efectivamente, también lo resolví añadiendo estas líneas antes del RewriteRule:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/videos.*$