# convertir 2 parámetros GET en URL Amigable y gestionarlos en PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

espero que me puedan ayudar con un problema que me tiene un poco despistado. Intentaré explicarme bien. Las url que pongo son a modo de ejemplo.

Convertir urls del tipo: midominio/page=noticias&code=25 (por ejemplo)
a => midominio/noticias/25

tendré que poder acceder a esas variables $_GET desde código PHP de la forma:
$_GET["page"] y $_GET["code"]

En .htaccess tengo esto,pero no me funciona

```
# Url Amigables
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/&=]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/&=]+)$ index.php?page=$1&code=$2
```

he probado el método de que page reciba por ejemplo "noticias/25" y luego con explode partirlo, pero no me convence, además pierdo los accesos a los css, js, etc.

Alguna ayuda o recomendación por favor?
Un saludo

Comment: Creo que [esto te puede servir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967). Si tienes alguna duda me dices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero contestar correctamente y haber ayudado, podría probar con:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ index.php?page=$1&code=$2 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Explicación:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z-_]
```

Te permite poner números, letras mayúsculas y minúsculas y guiones bajos "_".
El parametro [QSA] si no me equivoco, permite añadir a la url parametros GET en la url.

Para que no pierdas los CSS y demás podrías definir una variable global con la url:

```
define('url_base', '//'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/nombreProyecto/');
```

Y usarla de esta forma como ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= url_base ?>public/css/main.css"/>
```

Al tener la ruta absoluta no se perderá el archivo CSS o imagen o script JS por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucho tu ayuda. Un cordial saludo