# hola estoy tratando de recibir la id mediante get

Tags: php

hola estoy tratando de recibir la id mediante get

`http://localhost/softwareEdu/editarActividad/12`

que es para poder editar las actividades montadas y este es lo que uso

modelo:

```
// se encarga de buscar las actividades por id

    public function SearchOneActividad($id){
        $stmtdos = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades WHERE id ='$id'");
        $stmtdos->execute();
        $e  = $stmtdos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //var_dump($e);
        return $e;
    }

// se encarga de actualizar las actividad

    public function UpdateActividad ($datos){
        extract($datos);
        $stmtuno = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE actividades SET nombre = '$nombre',clasificacion ='$clasificacion',foto ='$foto',foto_url= '$foto_url',video_url= '$video_url',contenido= '$contenido' WHERE id = '$id'");
        $stmtuno->execute();
    }
```

controlador:

```
 <?php

    require_once "./modelos/actividadModelo.php";
    
    class actividadControlador extends actividadModelo{
        public function viewInsert(){
            require './vistas/contenido/insertActividad-view.php';
        }
    
        public function SaveInfoForModel($nombre, $clasificacion, $contenido, $foto, $fotourl, $video_url){
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
            $this->clasificacion = $clasificacion;
            $this->contenido = $contenido;
            $this->foto = $foto;
            $this->video_url = $video_url;
            $this->foto_url = $fotourl;
            $this->InserActividad();
            $this->redireccion();
        }
    
        public function UpdateInfoForModel($id,$nombre, $clasificacion, $contenido, $foto, $fotourl, $video_url){
            $datos = array(
                'id'            => $this->id = $id,
                'nombre'        => $this->nombre = $nombre,
                'clasificacion' => $this->clasificacion = $clasificacion,
                'contenido'     => $this->contenido = $contenido,
                'foto'          => $this->foto = $foto,
                'video_url'     => $this->video_url = $video_url,
                'foto_url'      => $this->foto_url = $fotourl
            );
            $this->UpdateActividad($datos);
            $this->redireccion();
        }
    
        public function ListView(){
            $a = $this->SearchAllActividad();
            require './vistas/plantilla.php';
            return $a;
        }
    
        /*public function editarActividad(){
            $id = $_GET['id']; echo $id;
            $a = $this->SearchOneActividad();
            //require './vistas/plantilla.php';
            return $a;
        }*/
        public function mostrarActividad($id){
            $e = $this->SearchOneActividad($id);
            require './vistas/plantilla.php';
            return $e;
        }
    
    
        public function redireccion(){
            header("location: administracionAct");
        }
    }
    
        if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='insert') {
            $instanciaactividad = new actividadControlador();
            $instanciaactividad->ViewInsert();
        }
    
        if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='insert') {
            $instanciaactividad = new actividadControlador();
            $foto = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
            $fototemporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
            $fotourl =  SERVERURL."vistas/assets/imgActividad/" . $foto;
            copy($fototemporal,$fotourl);
            $instanciaactividad->SaveInfoForModel(
                $_POST['nombre'],
                $_POST['clasificacion'],
                $_POST['contenido'],
                $foto,
                $fotourl,
                $_POST['video_url']);
        }
    
        //actualizar registros
            if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='update') {
            $instanciaactividad = new actividadControlador();
            $foto = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
            $fototemporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
            $fotourl =  "./vistas/assets/imgActividad/".$foto;
            copy($fototemporal,$fotourl);
            $instanciaactividad->UpdateInfoForModel(
                $_POST['id'],
                $_POST['nombre'],
                $_POST['clasificacion'],
                $_POST['contenido'],
                $foto,
                $fotourl,
                $_POST['video_url']
            );
        }
    // aca obtenemos el ID del registro a editar para que sea enviado a el controlador.
        $url = $_GET['views'];
        $idtemporal  = explode('/',$url);
        $id =$idtemporal[1];
    //*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/
    
    if (isset($_GET['views']) && $_GET['views']=='administracionAct') {
        $instanciaactividad = new actividadControlador();
        $instanciaactividad->ListView();
    }
    
        if (isset($_GET['views']) && $_GET['views']== 'editarActividad/'.$id) {
            $editaractividad = new actividadControlador();
            $editaractividad->mostrarActividad($id);
        }
```

la vista de administrar:

```
       <ul class="ulAdmin">
  <?php foreach ($a as $value): ?>
    <li class="liAdmin">
      <div class="divAcmin">
        <?php echo $value->video_url; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="divAcmin2">
        <h3><?php echo $value->nombre; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $value->contenido; ?></p>
        <h5 class="h5Acmin"><?php echo $value->clasificacion; ?></h5>
      </div>
      <a href="<?php echo SERVERURL;?>editarActividad/<?php echo $value->id ?>" action="editar"><h5>Editar Actividad</h5></a>|
      <a href="<?php echo SERVERURL;?>eliminarActividad/<?php echo $value->id ?>"><h5>Eliminar Actividad</h5></a>
      <!-- <a href="<?php //echo SERVERURL;?>editarActividad?id=<?php //echo $value->id ?>" action="editar"><h5>Editar Actividad</h5>  </a> -->
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

la vista de editar

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-row">
<?php foreach ($e as $actividad) : ?>
<div class="col">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $actividad->id; ?>">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre de la actividad</label>
    <input type="text"  required="requiered" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de la actividad" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $actividad->nombre; ?>">
  </div>

  <div class="col">
   <label for="nombre">Seleccione Trimestre</label>
   <select name="clasificacion"  required="requiered" class="form-control">
      <option value="Trimestre1">Trimestre 1</option>
   </select>
  </div>

   </div>
   <br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contenido">escribe el contenido que desea colocar</label>
    <textarea name="contenido" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="escribe el contenido que desea colocar" required="requiered"> <?php echo $actividad->contenido;?></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <label for="nombre">iframe del video</label>
    <textarea required="requiered" class="form-control" placeholder="iframe del video" name="video_url">
      <?php echo $actividad->video_url;?>
    </textarea>
  </div>
    <br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nuestroinput">Imagen o pdf</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="imagen" accept=".jpg , .png , .gif , .pdf">
    <img src="<?php echo SERVERURL;?><?php echo $actividad->foto_url;?>">
  </div>

  <br>

  <button>Guardar</button>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</form>
```

si funciona si hace lo que quiero pero no sé cómo tomar el id de otra forma les explicó porque cuando estoy en otra vista me da un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando estoy en la vista que corresponde no de el error ese pero si edita.

Yo sé porque da el error que es esta línea `$id =$idtemporal[1];`  que está en el controlador porque lo muestra en todas la vistas, pero no se me ocurre cómo hacer para que no me dé el error y que me tome el id.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es mantener la logica que tienes y eliminar ese error podrías intentar agregarle una validación.

```
if( !isset($_GET['id']) ){ 

   // Aqui se asigna la variable
}
```

tambien lo puedes intentar con empty:

```
if( empty($_GET['id']) ){ 

     // Aqui se asigna la variable

}
```

Tambien si quieres usar otra manera de optener un parametro es con el metodo post: `$_POST['id']`.
Espero haber te respondido la pregunta.

Comment: me puedes dar un ejemplo con el metodo post.   Y   con lo del if que me diste me pudes dar un ejemplo porfa

Comment: Creo que esta solución te ayudara mucho para lo que necesitas:   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/341661/convertir-2-par%C3%A1metros-get-en-url-amigable-y-gestionarlos-en-php