# Error al recuperar variable desde url amigable

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de recuperar una variable desde una url amigable, mediante GET,tengo un boton con un href="mi-perfil/id" donde id puede ser cualquier numero es decir seria "mi-perfil/1".

En htaccess tengo una regla de la siguiente forma

```
RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/([0-9]+)$ mi-perfil/mascota.php?id=$1
```

Luego en el archivo mi mascota.php, recupero la variable "id" sin ningun problema con jquery de la siguiente forma, para luego trabajar con ella mediante ajax y hacer consultas a la base de datos. Hasta ahi todo bien.

```
var id = '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>';
```

El problema surge si quiero presentar la url de otra forma, es decir en el boton pongo un href="mi-perfil/mascota/id" y en el htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/([0-9]+)$ mi-perfil/mascota/mascota.php?id=$1
```

Luego al intentar recuperar la variable mediante GET en jquery me da error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Que puedo estar haciendo mal ? , porque de una forma si puedo recuperar la variable id y de la otra forma no ?

Comment: El archivo `mascota.php` lo moviste a la carpeta `mascota`? Porque sino el problema está ahí. La primera parte de la regla es correcta, pero la segunda probablemente tenga que seguir siendo igual a la regla anterior.

Comment: no existe la carpeta mascota, estoy tratando de de generar la url para que parezca que existe la carpeta mascota

Comment: Me refiero a la segunda parte: "mi-perfil/mascota/mascota.php?id=$1" El archivo "mascota.php" dentro de qué carpeta se encuentra? Si está dentro de "mi-perfil", entonces la regla debería ser: `RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/([0-9]+)$ mi-perfil/mascota.php?id=$1`.

Comment: exacto siii el archivo mascota.php esta dentro de la carpeta mi-perfil, si escribo la regla como tu mencionas e inteneto recuperar la variable id mediante jquery var id = '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>'; me da error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Perdón, pero hablás de jQuery pero el ID los estás obteniendo por PHP. Podrías publicar el resultado de `<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>`?

Comment: Al parecer, tu regla debería ser: `RewriteRule ^mi-perfil/mascota/([0-9]+)$ mi-perfil/mascota.php?id=$1`

Comment: Para pasar datos con URLs amigables podrías valerte de `$_GET['PATH_INFO']` y armar lógica a partir de ahí. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967) hay código PHP explicando cómo podrías usar `PATH_INFO` para recuperar valores y para determinar además puntos de entrada (controlando únicamente aquellos que sean permitidos).