# Rutas en MVC usando ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mvc

[image: Tengo la siguiente estructura MVC]

En ***app.js*** tengo el codigo ajax y en ***cursos.php*** la funcion a la cual quiero hacaer referencia, pero no me ha funcionado hasta el momento.

***CODIGO ACTUAL***

***APP.js***

> Cita en bloque

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#curso").change(function() {    
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var dataString = 'empid='+ id;
    // Se puede eliminar
    console.log(id + ' Si funcionamos');    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Admin/obtenDato',  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< *** VER AQUI ***
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,  
        cache: false,
        success: function(employeeData) {
            alert("nice");
            // if(employeeData) {
            //  $("#no_records").hide();                    
            //  $("#emp_nombre").text(employeeData.claveCurso);
            //  $("#emp_edad").text(employeeData.objetivo);
            //  // $("#emp_salario").text(employeeData.salario_personal);
            //  $("#records").show();        
            // } else {
            //  $("#records").hide();
            //  $("#no_records").show();
            // }    
        } 
    });
}) });
```

y quiero hacer uso de esta funcion que se encuentra en cursos.php

```
 public function obtenDato()
    {
        $empid = $_REQUEST['empid'];
        $u = 1;
        if ($u == $empid) {
            echo "todo bien";
        }
    }
```

y el problema es que no se como colocar la ruta(url) en la parte mencionada en ajax

```
.ajax({
    url: 'Admin/obtenDato',  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< *** AQUI ***
```

tambien probe de otras maneras pero no me funciono.

Comment: Tu archivo se llama `cursos.php`  y es lo que tienes que poner en la URL, a no ser que estés implementando URLs amigables, como se hace en algunas APIs, de modo que puedes hacer llamadas así por ejemplo: `https://api.github.com/user/1` donde pides el usuario con id igual a `1`, pero en backend has programado código para redigir todo eso. ¿Es tu caso? Si no lo es, debes saber que no puedes llamar una función de PHP vía URL con tan solo ponerlo en la URL.

Comment: [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967) creo que están los pasos básicos para implementar URLs amigables, que te permitirán hacer llamadas al estilo de las APIs conocidas, poniendo algo como `persona/7` si quisieras los datos de la persona con id igual a 7.

Comment: gracias a los dos pero ya pude solucionar el problema, como dice A. Cedano no se puede acceder a la funcion via URL, fue necesario crear un nuevo archivo y en esta crear la funcion en dicho archivo.   de esta manera ***../../[nombre del proyecto]/Config/curso.php***

Comment: Sin embargo puedes dirigir todas las peticiones a un archivo `index.php` que haga de Controlador y desde allí conectar con otros archivos o con un Modelo de datos y usar la Vista para las salidas por pantalla. Eso te ayudará a centralizar el código, no teniendo que crear un archivo por cada función/petición Ajax.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, boi checar esa parte