# ¿Como puedo hacer recursiva la funcion y asi poder navegar entre carpetas desde el mismo index?

Tags: php, html

No quiero un bolcado de carpetas y archivos en la misma pagina, si no poder navegar entre carpetas con el mismo index y no tener que poner el archivo index en cada carpeta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>M07</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

        $contingut = "";

        if($handle = opendir('.')){
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){

                if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "index.php") && ($file != "desktop.ini")){

                    $contingut .= '<a id="enllaç" href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br><br>';
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
?>
<?php echo $contingut ?>
```

Comment: ¿Has pensado en hacer esto vía `.htaccess`? [He aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentas se parece mucho a lo que hacen en este post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function

```
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()) {
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
        $results[] = $path;
        } else if (($value != ".") && ($value != "..") && ($value != "index.php") && ($value != "desktop.ini")) {
            getDirContents($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$archivos = getDirContents(".");

//Esto de aqui no lo he probado
foreach($archivos as $archivo){
    $contingut .= '<a id="enllaç" href="'.$archivo.'">'.$archivo.'</a><br><br>';
}
```