# Pasar parámetros mediante post desde ajax usando rutas amigables en php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, php7, .htaccess

Tengo un sitio web con php y trabja con rutas amigables

Mi archivo `htaccess` es el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)\/?([a-z0-9]*)$ router.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

Mi archivo `router.php` es este:

```
<?php
  include_once("includes/config.php");
  include_once("includes/clases/class.Contacto.php");

  $pagina = $_GET["var1"];
  $id_contacto = $_GET["var2"];

  if(empty($pagina))
    $path = "index";
  else
    $path = $pagina;

  include "./".$path.".php";
?>
```

En mi archivo `registrar.php` mediante **ajax** envío parámetros por el metodo **post** a otra página en la cual se reciben y se procesan para posteriormente guardarlos en una base de datos.

Archivo `registrar.php`

```
function insert()
{
    var formulario = $("#form-registro");
    
    if(formulario.valid())
    {
       var nombre = $("#nombreVal").val();
       var apellidoP = $("#apellidoPVal").val();
       var apellidoM = $("#apellidoMVal").val();
       var telCasa = $("#telCasaVal").val();
       var telCelular = $("#telCelularVal").val();
       var correo = $("#correoVal").val();
       var calle = $("#calleVal").val();
       var numero = $("#numeroVal").val();
       var colonia = $("#coloniaVal").val();
       var codPostal = $("#codPostalVal").val();
       var ciudad = $("#ciudadVal").val();
       var estado = $("#estadoVal").val();
    
       $.ajax({
          url: "includes/acciones/contacto/insert.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: "nombre=" + nombre + "&apellidoP=" + apellidoP + "&apellidoM=" + apellidoM
              + "&telCasa=" + telCasa + "&telCelular=" + telCelular + "&correo=" + correo
              + "&calle=" + calle + "&numero=" + numero + "&colonia=" + colonia
              + "&codPostal=" + codPostal + "&ciudad=" + ciudad + "&estado=" + estado,
          success: function(data){
                if(data >= 1)
                {
                    Swal.fire('Contacto registrado correctamente!!!!', '', 'success').then((result) => {
                       if(result.value) {
                         window.location.reload(true);
                       }
                    });
                }
                else            
                  Swal.fire('No se pudo registrar el contacto!!!!', '', 'error');
          }
       });
    }      
}
```

La duda que tengo es como tendría que definir la url en el ajax:

**Primera Opción:**

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/includes/acciones/contacto/insert"
```

**Segunda Opción:**

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/includes/acciones/contacto/insert.php"
```

Y entonces también me sale como duda, si los parámetros tengo que pasarlos así como lo tengo actualmente o tendría que ser mediante un objeto literal o un json o un FormData o cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo??

Tengo un ejemplo en el cual manejan axios y en la url usan rutas amigables, y quiero pensar que sería algo similar con jquery pero como seria??

```
document.querySelector('.btn-guardar')
      .addEventListener('click', () => {
        let nombre = document.querySelector('input[name="nombre"]').value;
        let vencimiento = document.querySelector('input[name="vencimiento"]').value;
        let id = document.querySelector('#identificador').value;
        axios.post(`http://localhost/mvc/tareas/${id == "" ? 'create' : 'update'}`, {
            nombre,
            vencimiento,
            id
          })
          .then((r) => {
            let info = r.data;
            if (id == "") {
              // Agregar
              let tr = document.createElement("tr");
              tr.setAttribute('data-id', info.id);
              tr.innerHTML = `<td>${info.id}</td>
                              <td>${info.nombre}</td>
                              <td>${info.vencimiento}</td>
                              <td><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditar'>Editar</button>
                              <button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminar'>Eliminar</button></td>`;
              document.getElementById("table")
                .querySelector("tbody").append(tr);
              tr.querySelector('td:last-child .btnEditar')
                .addEventListener('click', fetchTarea);
              tr.querySelector('td:last-child .btnEliminar')
                .addEventListener('click', deleteTarea);
            } else {
              // Editar
              let tr = document.querySelector(`tr[data-id="${id}"]`);
              let cols = tr.querySelectorAll("td");
              cols[1].innerText = info.nombre;
              cols[2].innerText = info.vencimiento;
            }
            myModal.hide();

          })
      })
```

Comment: Quizá estés algo confundido pensando que las rutas amigables se manejan en la forma de poner el parámetro `url` de una petición Ajax y no, no está ahí el *quid* de la cuestión, tiene más bien que ver con organizar las carpetas en el servidor, y en la carpeta principal tener un archivo que haga de controlador de rutas. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967). Creo que puede arrojar un poco más de luz al respecto.

Comment: @A.Cedano mi archivo router.php es el que controla las rutas, pero la duda esta en como debo definir la url de la petición ajax, si es como alguna de las opciones que puse o tiene que ser de otra forma

Comment: Si usas rutas amigables, tú puedes mandar algo así: `tudominio.com/api/user/1` en un petición del tipo GET eso significaría: *obténme el `user` cuyo id es igual a `1`*, luego en el controlador debes verificar que `user` es un punto de entrada válido, obtener el valor del siguiente parámetro (el valor `1`) y ejecutar según el tipo de petición (si es GET obtener el `user` cuyo id es `1`). Esa es más o menos la lógica a seguir. Es importante que haya un orden, y que lo que hagas responda a algún estándar.

Comment: [Mira aquí por ejemplo](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) o en otras páginas. Hay varios estándares para organizar las rutas de una API o se un Servicio Web. Tener rutas estandarizadas te ayudará mucho, porque todo va acoplado a otras capas del programa, como la base de datos, el modelo de datos, etc. Por poner un ejemplo, si tienes en la BD una tabla llamada `user`, otra llamada `post`, otra llamada `account`, todas ellas serán puntos de entrada de tu API los cuales servirán para obtener, enviar, borrar ... entidades de ese tipo, según el tipo de petición que envíes en cada caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de poner un ejemplo en donde usan axios y en la url ponen una ruta amigable y quiero hacer lo mismo pero con jquery

Comment: Es más o menos lo mismo que te vengo diciendo, ahí se piden las ¿tareas? por su id ¿? Siendo acordes con la convención de nombre, si es una sola tarea, se debería poner en singular, no en plural. Aunque no conozco Axios, y no sé que signifique lo que hay después (`create` ... `update`). Los mismos métodos `http` ya indican el tipo de acción a ejecutar, como podrás ver [aquí](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html). En ese contexto, si mandas por el método `post` se debería sobre-entender que es un `create` lo que estás enviando.